# Change button name on ipywidgets

Tags: widget, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

Is there a way to easily change the button name in the ipywidgets module? I am using the decorator, but cannot find in the documentation how to change the name to something other than "Run Interact". I believe I need to use the decorator since my function needs to be run on demand and depends on multiple inputs from different widgets, but I'm open to other ways of doing so as well.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

@widgets.interact_manual(number1 = widgets.Dropdown(
                                            options=[1,2],
                                            description='select a number'),
                         number2 = widgets.Dropdown(
                                            options=[3,4],
                                            description='select another number'))
def add_numbers(number1,number2):
    return number1+number2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A bit quick and dirty but you can set

`widgets.interact_manual.opts['manual_name'] = 'Your text here'`

before defining your function and this should change the label name. If you have multiple `interact_manual` calls that need different labels you will need to change it each time.

---

```python
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

widgets.interact_manual.opts['manual_name'] = 'Your text here'

@widgets.interact_manual(number1 = widgets.Dropdown(
                                            options=[1,2],
                                            description='select a number'),
                         number2 = widgets.Dropdown(
                                            options=[3,4],
                                            description='select another number'),)
def add_numbers(number1,number2):
    return number1+number2
```